# regex find string in brackets and replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string: `Hello there [@Some Person](#/path/to/person). How are you? Where is your coffee? [@Another Person](#/path/to/another) said you are not great at regex.`

I want to replace all patterns like `[@Some Person](#/path/to/person)` to just `Some Person`.

So the final output of the aforementioned example should be: `Hello there Some Person. How are you? Where is your coffee? Another Person said you are not great at regex.`

So far I have:

```
> var re = /\[@([\w\s]+)\](\(\S+\))/g
> str.match(re)
> ["[@Some Person](#/path/to/person)", "[@Another Person](#/path/to/another)"]
// matches but not quite what I want.
> str.replace(re, $1)
> "Hello there undefined. How are you? Where is your coffee? undefined said you are not great at regex."
// does not replace as expected.
```

Here is my [regex sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/rS2iT2/1). I'd like to just use `str.replace` to get what I want. Not sure if that is possible. Seems like it should be. Please help.

Comment: What is your (incorrect) output? Looks like you're treating $1 as a variable. Probably just need to wrap it in quotes. it should be '$1'

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted, so I can't tell you. My guess would be because you didn't include incorrect output so we would theoretically have no idea "what's wrong".

Comment: I think I included the incorrect output of str.replace. But I won't flood this comment thread with speculation because it's irrelevant to the question. Thank you to all who helped.

Comment: My bad, I see it now, in the code block. (though it's kind of funny to say speculation. It's ok to call me out and say "I included it in the code block" :P ) It's either there or it's not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot double quotes around `$1`:

```
str.replace(re, "$1")
```

Comment: Thank you! Unbelievable!